# R Regex capture to remove/keep columns with repeats in their column names

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

This is an example dataframe

```
means2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=25, min=1, max=20), nrow=5))
names(means2) <- c("B_T0|B_T0", "B_T0|B_T1", "B_T0|Fibro_T0", "B_T5|Endo_T5", "Macro_T1|Fibro_T1")
```

I have column names in my dataframe in R in this format
\S+_T\d+|\S+_T\d+

The syntax is something like (Name)_ (T)(Number)  |  (Name)_ (T)(Number)

Step 1) I want to select columns which contain the same (T)(Number) on both sides of the "|"
I did this with some manual labor :

```
means_t0 <- means2 %>% select(matches("\\S+_T0\\|\\S+_T0")) %>% rownames_to_column("id_cp_interaction")
means_t1 <- means2 %>% select(matches("\\S+_T1\\|\\S+_T1")) %>% rownames_to_column("id_cp_interaction")
means_t5 <- means2 %>% select(matches("\\S+_T5\\|\\S+_T5")) %>% rownames_to_column("id_cp_interaction")
means3 <- full_join(means_t0, means_t1) %>% full_join(means_t5)
```

This gives me what I want and it was easy to do because I only had 3 types - T0, T1 and T5. What do I do if I had a huge number?

Step 2) From the output of Step1,  I want to do a negation of the last question i.e. select only those columns with Names which are not the same
For example B_T0|B_T0 should be removed but B_T0|Fibro_T0 should be retained

Is there a way to regex capture the part in front of the pipe(|) and match it to the part at the back of the pipe(|)

Thank you

Comment: Can you share a reproducible data set? It'll help understand the problem

Comment: Yes sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have that much information in your column names, I like to transform the data into the long format and then separate the info from the column name into several columns. Then it's easy to filter by these columns:

```r
means2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=25, min=1, max=20), nrow=5))
names(means2) <- c("B_T0|B_T0", "B_T0|B_T1", "B_T0|Fibro_T0", "B_T5|Endo_T5", "Macro_T1|Fibro_T1")
means2 <- cbind(data.frame(id_cp_interaction = 1:5), means2)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

res <- means2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -id_cp_interaction,
    names_to = "names",
    values_to = "values"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    celltype_1 = str_extract(names, "^[^_]*"),
    timepoint_1 = str_extract(names, "[0-9](?=|)"),
    celltype_2 = str_extract(names, "(?<=\\|)(.*?)(?=_)"),
    timepoint_2 = str_extract(names, "[0-9]$")
  )

head(res, n = 7)
#> # A tibble: 7 × 7
#>   id_cp_interaction names   values celltype_1 timepoint_1 celltype_2 timepoint_2
#>               <int> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>      <chr>       <chr>      <chr>      
#> 1                 1 B_T0|B…   1.68 B          0           B          0          
#> 2                 1 B_T0|B…  19.3  B          0           B          1          
#> 3                 1 B_T0|F…  10.6  B          0           Fibro      0          
#> 4                 1 B_T5|E…  12.5  B          5           Endo       5          
#> 5                 1 Macro_…   2.84 Macro      1           Fibro      1          
#> 6                 2 B_T0|B…   2.17 B          0           B          0          
#> 7                 2 B_T0|B…  10.1  B          0           B          1

# only keep interactions of different cell types
res %>% 
  filter(celltype_1 != celltype_2) %>% 
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 7
#>   id_cp_interaction names   values celltype_1 timepoint_1 celltype_2 timepoint_2
#>               <int> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>      <chr>       <chr>      <chr>      
#> 1                 1 B_T0|F…  10.6  B          0           Fibro      0          
#> 2                 1 B_T5|E…  12.5  B          5           Endo       5          
#> 3                 1 Macro_…   2.84 Macro      1           Fibro      1          
#> 4                 2 B_T0|F…   1.47 B          0           Fibro      0          
#> 5                 2 B_T5|E…  11.3  B          5           Endo       5          
#> 6                 2 Macro_…  13.0  Macro      1           Fibro      1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This is a cool way of doing it. Thanks! I can keep and remove the rows i want with dplyr filter

Comment: Is there a way to regex capture the part in front of the pipe and match it to the part at the back of the pipe and if they are the same do something etc

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. You can just filter the `celltype_1`/`celltype_2` columns, see my edit how to only keep interactions of different cell types

Comment: Very beautiful code. thanks a lot for your help!